# What does 染めちゃえ mean here?

Tags: translation, words, meaning, て-form, contractions

Saw this on twitter:

> A: マオにゃん、シドギャの彼女が出来ない僕に一言くれたら幸いです ...
>
> B: 付き合った後に**染めちゃえ**

What is 染めちゃえ here?

Comment: judging from your last question, you already know alot of japanese, so you should state what you know already.  Like "i know that Someru means to dye or color and chae is for shimau, but it doesn't make sense in this context."

Comment: tweets are *extremely* out of context. And I personnaly don't want JLU to become a tweet translation service. Please find an appropriate way to ask questions, showing efforts from your side, or an appropriate website to ask them.

Comment: I agree with Axioplase. You should at least remove the facemarks and other symbols that are not used in normal Japanese unless you think it is crucial for interpreting the sentence.

Comment: I agree with Mark that you should offer your knowledge by starting the translation, for things that you already understand. But I don't see anything bad with tweets (provided context is given), it is not like JLU is overflowed with questions...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just an idea: Maybe it means that someone has been in contact with X for so long that they have been influenced?

Like a white shirt would get a bit blue if you wash it together with blue clothes. A metaphor that can be found in French with "déteindre".

Comment: This sounds right. Basically "just date any old girl and **convert** her into a Sid fan"